# Como publicar um .EXE seguro, sem ser através do Click Once .Net

Tags: c#, .net, ftp, inno-setup

O meu cenário é composto da seguinte maneira:

Possuo aplicativos, que são configurados conforme cada cliente, são aplicativos vendidos em massa, tenho um sistema de apoio, que automatiza essa configuração e gera um executavel por cliente.

Após gerar esse executavel(Instalador Inno Setup), o mesmo e enviado para o ftp do nosso site, até ai tudo bem.

Porém, quando o cliente vai baixar esse sistema ele exibe aquela mensagem que o arquivo pode não ser seguro, se deseja manter.

ex: http://goo.gl/2OSqgV

O que preciso fazer para que esse arquivo possa se tornar "seguro", é algo no site? ou na aplicação? Estamos perdendo muitos clientes devido a essa complicação no download.

[upd]

Seguindo a dica do amigo tentei:

Mas ainda não consegui resolver meu problema, gerei o certificado através do **makecert**, dei o **sign**. O download ainda fica como se fosse **perigoso**.

Ai peguei esse certificado e **instalei** na **minha maquina**, ai o sistema detectou corretamente, porém não posso instalar esse certificado na maquina de cada cliente, será que sendo assim só posso utilizar os certificados pagos?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basicamente você vai precisar de um `Certificado Digital de Assinatura de Código`.

Há duas maneiras de se conseguir um `Certificado Digital`:

- Fornecedor Certificado - `Ex: Comodo`
- Gerar seu próprio certificado com [Makecert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bfsktky3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

E Para você assinar o `aplicativo` pode usar uma ferramenta de `Authenticode` da microsoft o [SignCode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/vstudio/9sh96ycy(v=vs.90).aspx).

Para ter mais conhecimentos sobre isso sugiro dar uma pesquisada sobre `Certificado Digital`, `Authenticode`, etc.

> Gerar o seu próprio certificado não é uma opção válida, vide que ele
>   serve apenas para testes. O uso de um certificado só faz sentido pelo
>   fato dele ser emitido por uma entidade que é considerada confiável
>   pelo seu navegador e ela pode confirmar que o certificado realmente é
>   válido. - @Leandro Godoy Rosa

Links para consulta:

[Implantação e a assinatura de Authenticode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/w9x9fdbk%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

[Comodo](http://www.comodobr.com/produtos/certificado_codesigning.php)

[Certificado Digital](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificado_digital)

Comment: Criando meu próprio Certificado, posso ter algum problema? Porque seria vantagem comprar? caso posso fazer o meu?
Obrigado pela resposta @MeuChapeu já clareou algumas coisas.

Comment: Creio que não teria problema em criar o próprio certificado, porém ele não seria emitido por uma `Certificadora Digital`.  Da uma olhada neste link --> http://www.devmedia.com.br/gerando-um-certificado-digital-proprio/31506

Comment: Posso ter entendido errado, mas ainda não consegui resolver meu problema, gerei o certificado, dei o sign. O download ainda fica como se fosse perigoso, ai peguei esse certificado e instalei na minha maquina, ai o sistema detectou corretamente, porém não posso instalar esse certificado na maquina de cada cliente, será que sendo assim só posso utilizar os certificados pagos?

Comment: Gerar o seu próprio certificado não é uma opção válida, vide que ele serve apenas para testes. O uso de um certificado só faz sentido pelo fato dele ser emitido por uma entidade que é considerada confiável pelo seu navegador e ela pode confirmar que o certificado realmente é válido.

Comment: Exatamente isso que o @LeandroGodoyRosa.

Comment: @MeuChapeu acho que vc pode complementar sua resposta com o comentário do Leandro.

Comment: @MeuChapeu um servidor, contendo um certificado SSL, poderia auxiliar em alguma coisa?